# How can the "Language Level" option be set to 7.0 and still produce an app that doesn't crash on startup

Tags: android, android-studio

Since Android Studio v0.32, there's a "Language level" option, which allows some java 7 features to be used. The problem is that I can't get any app to run correctly if the language level is set to 7.0

As a simple test, I made a new project using all the default options, except changing the language level to 7.0. The result, depending on which jdk is used when building is as follows:

with jdk-6:
 The app doesn't build. Gradle returns "invalid source release: 1.7"

with jdk-7:
  An apk is built. However, when gradle reaches the "dexDebug" step, the gradle console is flooded with "**bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0033.0000)**". None of the app classes are actually put into the apk, which leads to an **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException** on start.

So am I missing something here, or is there really no way to actually use the features that are advertised here: http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio032released

Comment: it happens only if JAVA 1.6 is trying to compile JAVA 1.7 code. Please include the output of `java -version`(inside command prompt) in your question and which java 7 feature you are using in your project.

Comment: everything is working fine for me. I have used all new java 7 feature together in one test project and it  worked like a charm. so nothing wrong in advertisement.

Comment: @pyus13, I'm not sure what you though 'jdk-7' meant, but the java version that produces the bad class errors is "1.7.0_45". Here's your prompt, just in case: $ java -version       
java version "1.7.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)

Comment: have you tried this  Settings> Compiler > Java Compile , set javac and project bytecode version 1.6 ?

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question. Be mindful if there are multiple instances of the sdk installed. One of them might not be kept up-to-date, yet be the currently default one in android studio.

This was my case. The offending sdk didn't have version 19 of the build tools.

Comment: did you success in using JDK7 or fallback somehow to JDK6?